# XSLT -> XHTML: Inline PHP?

Tags: php, xslt

I'm trying to use XSLT to generate some XHMTL with inline PHP.  I've run across a problem with generating inline PHP in attributes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"
       indent="yes"
       doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
       doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="<?php echo getLang(); ?>" xml:lang="<?php echo getLang(); ?>">
      <head>
 <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">include_title();</xsl:processing-instruction>

(Much more code ...)
```

gives the following results:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <?php include_title();?>

(Much more code ...)
```

Take note that the "lang" and "xml:lang" attributes of the html element are empty!  So clearly, this is the wrong way to process inline PHP.

So does anyone know how to change the xsl code to get the desired result shown below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="<?php echo getLang(); ?>" xml:lang="<?php echo getLang(); ?>">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <?php include_title();?>

    (Much more code ...)
```

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Just to get the point: you want the return values from `getLang()` to be integrated into the transformation result during the transformation, while you want `<?php include_title();?>` to be included literally in the transformation output?

Comment: Or do you want to have the transformation output to include the PHP instruction `<?php echo getLang(); ?>` literally inside the attribute?

Comment: I would like the XSLT output to give the bottom PHP script with the <?php echo getLang(); ?> literally inside the attribute.  This is so the dynamic nature of the webpage can be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the option of using XSLT 2.0? If you do, you can use [character maps](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps). Like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"
       indent="yes"
       doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
       doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
       use-character-maps="php"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="php">
    <xsl:output-character character="«" string="&lt;"/>   
    <xsl:output-character character="»" string="&gt;"/>
  </xsl:character-map>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="«?php echo getLang(); ?»" xml:lang="«?php echo getLang(); ?»">
      <head>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">include_title();</xsl:processing-instruction>
      </head>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like the way you think.  This may be the solution, but I can't test it.  I'm using the PHP5 XSL module, which uses libxslt version 1.1.22.  As far as I can tell, it only supports XSLT1.0.  :(

Comment: The XSLT 1.0 spec does not allow disabling output escaping for attribute values. I guess there is no way to get XSLT 1.0 to output unescaped angle brackets within attribute values. Perhaps could just add a "character map" style post processing stage after your XSLT transform?

Comment: After reading your suggestion yesterday that is exactly what I did using the str_replace() PHP function.  I would prefer a less "messy" solution, but this works for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

&lt;?php ... &gt;

Comment: This just gives the following result:
lang="&lt;?php echo getLang(); ?&gt;"
Sorry, try again.

Answer (score 1):

maybe using the same directive you used for this:

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="php">include_title();</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

if you just echo getLang(), is it actually returning anything? Your code and environment description is very limited, so it is hard to tell what is getting processed as PHP, and what is getting processed by an XSLT processor.

What happens if you replace `<?php echo getLang();?>` with 
`<?php echo '<?php echo getLang();?>' ;?>`

Comment: Interesting idea.  When I try this, I get the error message: "Unescaped '<' not allowed in attribute values."

Comment: If there is some more information you need please ask.  I didn't include all the code and environment information because it seems to be superfluous.